# How to reset Launchpad ordering in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos

Previously I can remove the files end with `db` in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/` to reset the ordering of apps, but now doing the same thing doesn’t help. Do anyone know where the new path that organizes the Launchpad is located?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Enter this line in the console:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

Removing the db doesn't seem to do the trick any more. So this two steps are necessary to reset the Launchpad in Yosemite:

> 1. rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db ; killall Dock
> 2. defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock

Comment: Killing Dock once is enough from my try: `rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db; defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`

Comment: this does not work anymore either

Comment: it seems that simply `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock` will do now.

Answer (score 2):

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db
rm "/$TMPDIR../0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db/db*"
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

Answer (score 1):

Here Launchpad resets, when deleting the three database files in...

```
/private/var/folders/02/yff1cxtx61v3y1pydkt96j2h0000gn/0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db/db
/private/var/folders/02/yff1cxtx61v3y1pydkt96j2h0000gn/0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db/db-shm
/private/var/folders/02/yff1cxtx61v3y1pydkt96j2h0000gn/0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db/db-wal
```

...and restarting the Dock: `killall Dock`

I get there by opening

```
open $TMPDIR../0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db/
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Yosemite, simply running `killall Dock` wont always cut it when altering your `defaults`.

In Yosemite the `defaults` are now cached in two separate persistent processes called `cfprefsd`; one owned by you, `$USER`, and the other owned by `root`, so you essentially need to restart these processes.

You can verify this by opening up Activity Monitor.app and searching for `cfprefsd` 
(There can actually be more than two of these process in some circumstances, not to worry though!)

I added the following one liner to my shell profile of choice (.zshrc) so that it is easily available to me anytime by just typing `fixpref`, but you also can just cut out the good parts to use it once!

TL;DR:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Clear defaults caches, reload them, and then kill everything!
alias fixpref='sudo killall -SIGKILL cfprefsd && killall Dock && killall Finder'
```