# How to remove an empty group in Launchpad

Tags: macos, applications, launchpad

I installed Google IME and uninstalled it. Then, as shown in the image below, an empty group is left in Launchpad. (I think it should have been removed automatically when the group became empty.) How can I remove the empty group manually?

OSX 10.10.2[image]

Comment: Did you try to restart your Mac?

Comment: @gruberb I restarted my MacBookPro (Late 2012) many times and tried Command+R, reinstalling Yosemite once. But, the empty group is still there.

Comment: Then have a look at this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150965/how-to-reset-launchpad-ordering-in-os-x-yosemite Caution: You'll loose your order and the Launchpad will be reset.

Comment: @gruberb Thanks for your suggestion. My MacBookPro is a Late 2012 model, which means that there are many apps organized in Launchpad. Given this, I would rather put up with the current situation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: One another solution can be: Wait until the update to 10.10.3 is out, so your empty folder will propably be gone. You can also look deeper and open the .pslist and look for this entry. (look at my link to apple.stackexchange above)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Previous answer didn't help me on Yosemite - when I dragged app into the empty folder the app just disappeared for a while and the folder was still there, empty and disturbing. But then I've found a way to fix it without resetting Launchpad:

Click and hold any random app until all icons start shaking, then drag the app on the folder, DON'T RELEASE, and drag back into its place. Right after dragging back the empty folder has disappeared.

Comment: Aldekein you are a god, thank you for solving this :)

Comment: @KirkOuimet you are welcome. Thank you for Scan! :)

Comment: When I saw Google search quoting this answer, I thought it was joke :P Can't believe a UX designer at Apple thought, "yup, that seems logical"

Comment: still worked for me macOS Catalina

Comment: Still works on Big Sur

Answer (score 5):

If you move an app into the empty folder and then go into that empty folder and drag the app back out onto the launchpad the empty folder will disappear.

Comment: You don't even have to drop the app into the folder. Using the answer provided by @aldekein above, after click-holding an icon until they all shake, if I drag any icon over an empty folder until it expands, then drop the icon outside of the folder, the folder disappears.