# Issue with my launchpad on MBP Retina 13"

Tags: macos, xcode, dock, launchpad, console

I've got one annoying problem with my launchpad icon. Today i was downloading xcode and i stopped it over the time, because it was already installed in the finder.

Can I reset the launchpad over my console ? It is still on the point of stopped, but i can't klick on it to download it again.

sudo killall -SIGKILL cfprefsd && killall Dock && killall Finder
 will not work for reset, another way, the reboot isn't working too.

Hope you can help me and sorry for my bad english, i hope you'll understand me (;

[image: The Icons]

[image]

Best regards,

Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Google search gave this article on [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/05/05/reset-launchpad-layout-mac-os-x/), which is interestingly based on this [Stack Exchange answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150973/96100). Here are the relevant bits:

> 1. Open the Terminal application and enter the following defaults write command string: 
>      `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`
> 2. Hit return and wait for the Dock to relaunch and Launchpad to reset
>
> When you open Launchpad again, **the layout will have returned to the
>   default, placing all bundled apps onto the first screen of Launchpad,
>   and third party apps onto the secondary (and third, if applicable)
>   screens.**