# Mac App Store Xcode download stuck at "Installing"

Tags: applications, install, xcode, mac-appstore, launchpad

I've pressed the "Update" button in the Mac App Store to install a new version of Xcode.

The Mac App Store itself [shows no visible download progress](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342605/app-download-progress-in-redesigned-mac-app-store-macos-mojave)  or error messages, but the circle is almost complete:

[image: Xcode circle almost complete]

Hovering on Launchpad's dock icon shows the ongoing Mac App Store download progress. Now that the download has completed it is showing "Launchpad Installing".

[image: Launchpad Installing]

> Launchpad Downloading - 100.0 MB of 12.39 GB
> Launchpad Installing

It's been stuck in this state for quite some time.

I'm currently using Xcode, which is open. I have had various Xcode betas installed, in addition to the Mac App Store version. The latest Xcode RC was simply titled "Xcode.app" and overwrote the version from the Mac App Store in my Applications directory.

As I'm typing this, the "Installing" seems to have finally failed. It has begun downloading the entire 12.39 GB update again.

Why is the Mac App Store download stuck at "Installing"? How can I get this update to actually install?

Comment: Hmmm happened to me on Monterey 12.0, updated, installed weird so I had two Xcodes, so I uninstalled them both because frankly I don't use them. Kudos on actually asking the question

Answer (score 29):

I just went through this. It does install, it just takes an obscene amount of time. Over 1 hour for me on an M1 macbook pro. It gets to 80% and stops downloading and starts using high cpu usage with a process "installd". Then it gets to 99% and the CPU usage is gone but it takes another 20 minutes to finish the install.

You can open the app "Console", start the logging, and search the logs for the process "App Store" to see detailed install percentages.

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer. Before I saw this answer I kept aborting after 2 or 3 hours of it sitting at what looked like it was complete. Once I realized I could see the % complete in the console it made me confident that if I waited long enough it would complete, and it did. It did take stupidly long though... maybe 5 hours?

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: I have the opposite experience. It downloaded and installed to 96.5% and then it just stuck there at full CPU. After an hour or two it stopped producing log messages and started downloading the *entire* 8 GB again. This install system is far from impressive, and using Appstore to install Xcode still seems like a mistake in 2023.

Answer (score 17):

I had this same issue myself today.

I was able to resolve the issue with the following steps:

- Move Xcode.app from my Applications folder to my Bin
- Force Quit the `appstoreagent` background process from Activity Monitor

  - This causes the Mac App Store to stop all in-progress updates, and it recognises I've removed the program.
- Reinstall Xcode from the App Store normally

Comment: This is what I ended up doing as well: move existing Xcode to the trash. I didn't quit the process but that might have sped things up.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest ditching the App Store version and going instead with the direct download from https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Once you have the `Xcode.xip` file, pop open a Terminal and decompress it using the command below (instead of double-clicking with Finder.app, which is slower):

```bash
xip -x Xcode.xip
```

Next **delete the old Xcode.app first** before trying to drag the new one to /Applications. This avoids the delay while Finder tries to calculate the diff of which hundreds of thousands of files may be overwritten, so will save considerable time.

Also of note, there is a tool called [`unxip`](https://github.com/saagarjha/unxip/) (GitHub link) which claims to decompress Xcode 200-300% faster than the native xip tool.

Comment: I run into this issue nearly every time I try to update Xcode via the App Store app. Installing via .xip seems to be the only reliable way.

Answer (score 5):

If you're an M1 user and this happens make sure you're plugged into your power adapter. I had this same issue until I plugged in.

Comment: I was stuck at 91% for hours and couldn't try your tip because I was already plugged.
So I unplugged and plugged again, and voila installation completed!

Answer (score 3):

After seeing Qwertie's answer above, I looked a bit more in the console log and saw the following entry:

```
503:com.apple.appstored.Sbsync:E1475B:[
    {name: ThermalPolicy,
     policyWeight: 5.000,
     response: {
         Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, 
         Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]
     }
    }
], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
```

After pulling out the external monitor, i.e making my Mac a bit cooler, it finished in a minute after having been stuck at part 979 for a long time.

Comment: Unreal. So it just sits there idle until the mac cools down? That would explain why it seemed to do nothing for 20 minutes after the CPU usage was gone.

Answer (score 2):

This was also happening to me on MacOS Ventura. Console with process "App Store" read a progress of 0.981, where it was frozen. Stopping Time Machine and ejecting the external volume seems to have fixed the issue, although it could've been coincidental since I didn't see any logs that indicated Time Machine was the culprit.