# My launchpad now resets spontaneously

Tags: launchpad

After following the procedure given in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232678/331833, my launchpad spontaneously resets itself!

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

Apps I pulled out of the "other" folder (because I use them regularly) returned to that folder.

Other apps that I have no interest in ever using (and sincerely wish the folks in Cupertino hadn't bundled), and which I'd put in either "Others" or a folder marked "Stuff I neither want nor need," cluttering up the first page of the launchpad.

(Oh, and the "Stuff I neither want nor need" folder itself disappears, and Eclipse moves back into a folder of its own.)

How do I fix this? Why is it resetting *every time* I reboot? Could it be the part before the semicolon? If so, how do I undo it?

Comment: Change the value to “false” and re-issue the command.  What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: I *was originally* trying to solve a problem of at least one application failing to show up in the Launchpad. That problem was solved; here, I was trying to solve the side effect of a solution that was worse than the problem. Evidently the solution given for https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232678/331833 (and the other threads it cited) was *intended* to force a launchpad reset on power-up (or on sign-on), and I simply failed to read the fine print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defaults delete` to reset the option so Launchpad is no longer is configured to reset itself on start.

```
defaults -currentHost delete com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad && killall Dock
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the right one

Comment: That did it. Thanks.